# Lose data in draggable List with nested ItemRenderers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I am suffering from this problem for a few days.
There is a List in which you can drag items.

```
[Bindable] public static var posts:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
[Bindable] private var dragit:Boolean = false;
protected function lst_itemClickHandler(evt:ItemClickEvent):void {
                if (evt.label == 'mousedown') {
                    dragit = false;
                    return;
                }
                if (evt.label == 'mouseup') {
                    dragit = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
<s:List id="list" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{posts}" itemRenderer="postIR" selectedIndex="0" dragEnabled="{dragit}" dragMoveEnabled="true" dropEnabled="true" useVirtualLayout="false"/>
```

This list have an item renderer (postIR) as part of which buttons, images, TextArea and another Tile List with his item renderer - socIR. 
Here is postIR:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                xmlns:c="*"
                autoDrawBackground="true" creationComplete="itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" maxHeight="120">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable] private var index:int;
            [Bindable] private var socDP:ArrayCollection;
protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                index = ((this.owner as List).dataProvider as ArrayCollection).getItemIndex(data);

                socDP = Copypaste.socialVector[index] as ArrayCollection;
                soc.addEventListener(ItemClickEvent.ITEM_CLICK, soc_itemClickHandler);
            }
//Deleted some code
]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <c:CheckList id="soc" width="100%" height="100%" itemRenderer="socIR" mouseDown="txt_mouseDownHandler(event)" mouseUp="soc_mouseUpHandler(event)"
            dataProvider="{socDP}" allowMultipleSelection="true" useVirtualLayout="false" click="soc_clickHandler(event)">
        <c:layout>
            <s:TileLayout requestedColumnCount="3" verticalAlign="top" padding="5"/>
        </c:layout>
    </c:CheckList>
    //Deleted some code
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Here is socIR:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" click="itemrenderer1_clickHandler(event)" creationComplete="itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" padding="5"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal"/>
        <s:State name="selected"/>
    </s:states>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function itemrenderer1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if (this.selected) {
                    data.selected = true;
                } else {
                    data.selected = false;
                }   

                var parentList:List = owner as List;
                var e:ItemClickEvent = new ItemClickEvent(ItemClickEvent.ITEM_CLICK, true);
                e.item = data;
                e.index = parentList.dataProvider.getItemIndex(data);
                e.label = "selected";
                dispatchEvent(e); 
            } 

             override public function set data(value:Object):void
            {
                super.data = value;
                 if (value.selected) {
                    data.selected = true;
                } else {
                    data.selected = false;
                }  
            }  

            protected function itemrenderer1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                if (data.selected) {
                    this.selected = true;
                } else {
                    this.selected = false;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:CheckBox id="socCheck" selected.selected="true" selected.normal="false" mouseEnabled="false"/>
    <s:Image source="{'images/socialicons/' + data.icon}"/>
    <s:Label text="{data.label}"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Everything works fine until I need to drag an items in main List. Selected items in socIR or disappear or randomly shuffled. I used a variety of methods - to store data when changing items in the main class in the vector for each itemrenderers - public static var socialVector:Vector. = new Vector.();
, but it only adds to the confusion. I experimented with useVirtualLayout, but it did not help.
Please any advice how to avoid issue with data loss when drag an item.
Thanks.

PS so looks my list
[image]

Comment: It is hard to get what is your problem. Is it possible to add the functional sample application and steps where you get an issue?

Comment: @gbdcool, I can't share the app because it is AIR. The steps are as follows: I select some checkboxes in socIR (see image above), drag any item in postIR, all checkboxes in socIR are unselected.